# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, mnist

I am using someone else code ([Code Link](https://github.com/shu-yusa/tensorflow-mirrored-strategy-sample/blob/master/cnn_mnist.py)) which is implemented in Tensorflow1. I want to run this code into Tensorflow2 However I am getting this error:

```
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I upgraded this code by using this instruction:

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
  --infile /research/dept8/gds/anafees/MyTest.py \
  --outfile /research/dept8/gds/anafees/MyTest2.py
```

Most things are updated, however generated report showed:

```
168:21: ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
```

I search google; however, I could not find any suitable solution. I do not want to move back to Tensorflow1. Is there any alternate solution? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Few libraries are deprecated in Tensorflow 2.x such `tf.contrib`, To make the code compatible with Tf 2 needs some changes in library.

Replace

```
tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
```

with

```
tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

And Replace

```
tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy
```

with

```
tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=None, cross_device_ops=None)
```